Seasonality adjustment method
I have a question on seasonal adjustment.
Let's say that I have PPI which is seasonally unadjusted. And, when I look at decomposition plot, I cannot detect seasonality.
However, I need to convert this PPI to growth rate(PPI based inflation: $\Delta \pi_t = PPI_t - PPI_{t-1}$). And now, when I look at the decomposition plot of this PPI-based inflation, I detect the presence of seasonality.
When should I apply the seasonality adjustment method TRAMO-SEATS? Should I apply the method directly to PPI? or Should I apply the method to the PPI-based inflation $\pi$ (1st difference)?
That's, which data should I apply the TRAMO-SEATS to remove seasonality in inflation when I do not detect any seasonality pattern in raw data PPI, but I detect seasonality in PPI-base inflation by using the PPI data?
In this point, please share your ideas with me. Thank you.
